# eclipse : Changing tabs to spaces in edited lines

Tags: eclipse, tabs, space

Is there a way in eclipse to change tabs to spaces only specifically in lines that have been edited ?

I know we can change the tabs to spaces over all but I want to only make a change to lines edited by the user in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find and Replace dialog for this.

Test data used.

```
fdff    fdfdf           fdfdfd
    dfdfdf  fdfdf fdfdf dfdfd fdfdf    fdfdfd
fdfdf
fd
fdf

fdff    fdfdf           fdfdfd
    dfdfdf  fdfdf fdfdf dfdfd fdfdf    fdfdfd
dfd

fdf
df
dfd
ffdfdf
```

line no 1,2 are copied to line number 7 and 8. Select line 7 and 8(Which has tabs and spaces) in editor. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> .

Ref pic below.

[image]

---

**Also refer [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) Plugin.**